# In which stack would I ask about categorizing things?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to categorize a collection of exactly 1000 objects (like for example:  car, cat, house, tree, flower, heart, foot, sky, ...) into 10 categories with 10 subcategories each.

Where would I ask if someone knows how to categorize objects in a most efficient way?

---

Why do I get more and more downvotes here all the time? I understood already, that StackOverflow is not for asking for resources ;)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. But generally speaking, asking for resources is off-topic on just about all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: So where would I ask then if someone knows how categorizing things is most efficient?

Comment: In what context? You are writing in such a vague way that I can't see what you are trying to say at all. Categorize _how_? Using _what_? Are you asking where to _find_ categories or how _to_ do so with existing data?

Comment: how to find categories

Comment: I believe I already answered that, at least in regards to the scope of Stack Exchange sites. I would argue that asking us where in the whole Internet you can ask something is also out of scope.

Comment: I want to find a pictogram for all numbers from 0 to 999 and put them into 10 categories

Comment: I have no idea what that would even look like. Why not make one yourself?

Comment: But most questions in StackExchange are answered with a solution that was found somewhere else in the Internet

Comment: They are about specific topics and not about finding resources.

Comment: I would wholeheartedly disagree with that @rubo77. Most questions on Stack Exchange are answered by people with experience of the subject they are answering.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Although I don't disagree with you, I can't resist pointing out that (ironically) the first answer to this question is a verbatim copy of the FAQ... It's not really something that "was found somewhere else in the Internet", but still.

Comment: I said most on purpose @Yannis :-). I know I've answered some questions with a quick search on the internets before.

Comment: Are you trying to physically sort and categorize a group of 1000 objects? Are you trying to sort data? Are you trying to sort images by content?

Comment: I try to sort Data.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming your actual question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870722/where-do-i-find-a-collection-of-1000-categorized-free-to-use-icon-sets and you're asking what Stack Exchange site is suitable for this question?

The answer to that is none. I'm sorry but there is no suitable Stack Exchange site. There are two reasons, as you have two questions in your own.

Firstly,

> I need an iconset, that I can use to develop a memorization-technique
> software, that displays a different distinct icon for each number from
> 0 to 999.
> ...
> Where would I find such a collection?

You're asking for someone to basically provide you with a link to something. To search the internet in other words. As there is no reasonably small set of answers to this question every answer, in a large set, is equally valid.

As explained in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Secondly,

> Or how would a scrip look like to automatically download the first three icons each from iconfinder.com for each word of a list?

You're asking for someone to do your work for you. This is not the correct way to approach Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange, it is not a free coding service but a community of people helping you for free in their free time. If you've created a script and are having problems with it then please feel free to post a question about your script.

As ever, and as Yannis points out in the comments, you could try your luck in a chat room. Yannis suggests [Graphic Design](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner) and so I'm heaping all the blame on him :-).

---

Quick extra point. If you do write a script to do what you suggest you want to then be wary of downvotes. Ensure you read Iconfinder's terms of service and licences. [You can't use a icon without permission.](http://support.iconfinder.com/customer/portal/articles/919724-am-i-allowed-to-use-a-free-icon-for-commercial-purposes-)

Comment: Chat, and more specifically [Graphic Design's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner), might be the only good place within SE to ask this.

Comment: Thanks @Yannis, I've updated my answer and blamed you :-).

Comment: thanks for your info. And sure, I would only use the free-to use icons from iconfinder ;)4